# Are 17″ MacBook Pro for sale by Apple?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-store

I have a 2010 Macbook Pro 17″

It does not have a Thunderbolt port. I believe about a year ago Apple released a 17" that had a thunderbolt port. I was thinking about upgrading to a newer 17" model but there is now 17" macbooks in the Apple Store. I want a new Mac, not anything from the refurbished section.

[image]

I checked [MacRumors](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/#MacBook_Pro) and there is no news about a newer 17". I also heard that a 17" with retina display seemed pretty impossible - because of the price / technology limitations etc.

Does Apple still sell a 17 inch portable Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your answer:
[Apple discontinues 17 inch MacBook Pro](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167248/apple_discontinues_17_inch_macbook_pro.html)

From the site:

> "But if you’re looking for a reason why Apple offed the 17-inch now, you need go no further than the 15-inch Retina display MacBook Pro. Not only does it offer the most cutting edge technology of any Apple laptop to date, but its 2880-by-1800 pixel display outstrips the 17-inch’s 1920-by-1200 resolution with room to spare. Add in the fact that the new MacBook Pro is thinner and lighter—to the tune of more than 2 pounds—and it seems pretty clear that the Retina display model is the new target for what a powerhouse portable should be."

Comment: damn. but i love the 17".

Answer (score 1):

Apple [discontinued the 17" MacBook Pro](http://www.theverge.com/2012/6/11/3078783/apple-quietly-discontinues-the-17-inch-macbook-pro) when they announced the 15" Retina MBP. It's fairly unlikely they'll make another one any time soon (probably never, if I were putting money on it). You may be able to get one refurbished or from a third party reseller with stock left.